# Visual Studio "Auto" width / height in XAML-Designer

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to build a UserControl in a UWP application and I'm not able to see its "Auto" size (based on its content) in the XAML-Designer.

I'm aware I can hardcode d:DesignHeight and d:DesignWidth to absolute values, but since the size should be based on its content, I don't want to hardcode the values.

Is there something like d:DesignHeight="Auto" / d:DesignWidth="Auto" ?

E.g. - for the sample User Control below

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyCompany.UserControls.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:MyCompany.UserControls.UserControls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="First" />
        <Button Content="Second" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I'm seeing

[image]

However I'd like to see the size of the control based on its content.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of the XAML designer. The control will still be sized properly at runtime.

However, this is a very good feedback and I suggest you send it as enhancement request in through Visual Studio feedback, I would definitely upvote it :-) .

Comment: I have logged a feedback suggestion here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1095041/visual-studio-auto-width-height-in-xaml-designer.html

Comment: Also reached out to Dmitry (Microsoft PM working on XAML) on twitter https://twitter.com/CosminStirbu/status/1277519484669112321?s=20

Answer (score 0):

If delete `d:DesignHeight`  & `d:DesignWidth` in user control, it will layout as to it's content.

if it doesn't, then you can add  `VerticalAlignment` & `HorizontalAlignment` to your user control while using.

```
<local:MyUserControl2  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"/>
```

It should work.